# CSS Vertical Menu - Having a border hovers issue

Tags: css

I want to be able to hover a link and not have the top border from the link below show up.
If you check out the fiddle you will see what I mean.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you =)

http://jsfiddle.net/p0wt9q6w/

Here is my CSS code:

```
#homeMenu {background:#d7d7d7;; position:relative; height:400px; top:20px;}
#homeMenu a {
  display:block; 
  color:#5d5d5d; 
  font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  padding: 20px 0; 
  border-top: 1px solid #fff; 
  border-bottom:1px solid #d7d7d7; 
  text-indent:15px; 
  text-decoration:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
      }
#homeMenu a:hover {background: #fff; color:#00694f; border-top:1px solid #00694f; border-bottom: 1px solid #00694f;}
#homeMenu a:first-child {border-top:1px solid #d7d7d7;}
#homeMenu a:first-child:hover {border-top:1px solid #00694f;}
#homeMenu a.active {background: #fff; color:#00694f; border-top:1px solid #00694f; border-bottom: 1px solid #00694f;}
#homeMenu span {position:absolute; right:15px;}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="homeMenu">
     <a href="#" class="homeMenuLink active" id="homelink1">What is a credit union <span>></span></a>
     <a href="#" class="homeMenuLink" id="homelink2">Open an Account <span>></span></a>
     <a href="#" class="homeMenuLink" id="homelink3">Calculators <span>></span></a>
     <a href="#" class="homeMenuLink" id="homelink4">News and Events <span>></span></a>
     <a href="#" class="homeMenuLink" id="homelink5">Online Payments <span>></span></a>
     <a href="#" class="homeMenuLink" id="homelink6">Online Appointments <span>></span></a>                
</div><!--homeMenu close-->
```

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want the border from the first element also showing when you hover the second element?

Comment: So if I'm hovering over the first element as shown in the fiddle, I don't want to see the top white border of the element below.

Comment: Your out of luck unless you use some javascript

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  My javascript skills are non-existant.

Comment: Why not just get rid the the border on hover? Just have the background color change.

Comment: I'm working on this page for my marketing team and thats what they want.  I told him to go back to the drawing board. =P  Thanks for all your help Nicholas.